# Error using ==> plot3 Conversion to double from cell is not possible. plot3(p(1,:),p(2,:),p(3,:),'+r');

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to call competitive layer on kdd data set, but I'm getting this:

```
???Error using ==> plot3 Conversion to double from cell is not possible. plot3(p(1,:),p(2,:),p(3,:),'+r');
```

Here is my code:

```
clear all;
p=importdata('kdd train.txt');
tar=[];
for i=0:size(p);
    tar=[tar;0 1];
end
net=newc(tar,5,0.1);
w = net.IW{1};
plot3(p(1,:),p(2,:),p(3,:),'+r');
grid on;
hold on;
circles = plot3(w(:,1),w(:,2),w(:,3),'ob');
net.trainParam.epochs = 10;
net = train(net,p);
w = net.IW{1};
delete(circles);
plot3(w(:,1),w(:,2),w(:,3),'ob');
```

Can anyone see what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that for the `p` variable there suppose to be a conversion to double from cell, so I assume `p` is a cell array and not a numeric matrix. Try to convert it using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
 p=cell2mat(p);
```

Comment: hi Natan,im getting this error after using this cell2mat function                                                            ???Error using ==> cat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> cell2mat at 89
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Comment: @sai What does your cell array contain? What are the dimensions of its contents?

Comment: Hi
 
im using KDD dataset(UCI Dataset) for intrusion dectection,
we can get data set here
http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/